# Silverlight webpage preview control

Tags: silverlight, html, preview

I'm making a silverlight app that when the user does a mouse-over some tab bars, he/she will see a preview of the page it will link to. The reason for this preview is that just having a visual miniature of the page is often enough to make the desicion for the user. How do I in Silverlight make a control that simply displays a webpage, preferably scaled down?

Cheers

Nik

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are probably aware, there are some issues relating to crossing domain boundaries in Silverlight. Issues that have been discussed on stack overflow [for example](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=silverlight+cross+domain).

This is relevant because generally you can't request web resources in other domains which you'd need to do here.

One way I've seen to get around this is to use a web service that doesn't have the same limitation. So you can create a web service that exposes a byte[] of the image and have the web service do the calls to retrieve the image and send it back to Silverlight.

Once you've got the image byte[] you can read that in an asynchronous call, and set the image source like this.

```
BitmapImage thumb;
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(imgArray))
{
    thumb = new BitmapImage();
    thumb.SetSource(stream);
}
```

The other issue is how to generate the thumbnail, for that you can [google](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=website+thumb+generator++.net), there are some projects that show you how and some public web services that do it for you. [Amazon's](http://aws.amazon.com/ast/) is one such example.

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing that out and providing these work around suggestions. I was expecting Silverlight to have something similar to the iPhoneSDK's UIWebView that hooked into the supported browsers. Cheers -Nik